# How to control the suggestion word block when key in some words in entry (Xamarin)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am implementing iOS/Android APP through Xamarin.

I found out that when set IsPassword for an entry to "false"

On my test mobile. When typing in this entry. There will no suggestion words.

If I set it to true. Then there will be suggestion words.

Is this a rule from google or apple? Is there any doc that explain this rule?

And is there any other way that I can control whether the suggestion word will appear or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I set entry ispassword as true, there is no suggestion words, set ispassword as false, there is suggestion words.

The Keyboard class also has a Create factory method that can be used to customize a keyboard by specifying capitalization, spellcheck, and suggestion behavior. KeyboardFlags enumeration values are specified as arguments to the method, with a customized Keyboard being returned.

The KeyboardFlags enumeration contains the following values:

**None, CapitalizeSentence, Spellcheck, Suggestions, CapitalizeWord, CapitalizeCharacter, CapitalizeNone, All**.

I guess that the Entry have the default suggestion words for keyboard, if you set ispassword as true, the contents of the field will be presented as black circles, the entry will prevent suggestion words.

About KeyboardFlags, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customize-the-keyboard